# Flutter - Get data from Firestore and save to Provider when app starts

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I need to get some data from Firestore and save it to Provider when the app first opens.

This is the first page that loads. It's a Stateful widget and I'm trying to grab the data like this:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final User user = Provider.of<User>(context, listen: false);
    _getItems(user);
  }

  _getItems(user) {
    final content = Provider.of<Content>(context, listen: false);
    //get data from Firestore using user.uid
    //save it to content.ids
    content.ids = {"1": 2};
  }
```

When doing this, I get the following error:

```
flutter: The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for Content:
flutter: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
flutter: This _InheritedProviderScope<Content> widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the
flutter: framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be
flutter: built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is
flutter: allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant
flutter: will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
flutter: The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
flutter:   _InheritedProviderScope<Content>
```

What is the best way to get data and save to Provider when app starts? I know that I have the `MultiProvider` option in `main.dart`, but I don't have a user id there.

Answer (score 0):

Stream your Auth data at the root of your app.

```
class AuthStream extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<User>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: Wrapper(),
    );
  }
}
```

Dont call Provider in initState() rather call it in your build method.

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    if (user == null) {
      return Login();
    } else {
      return Dashboard();
    }
  }
}
```

From there you would use the user.uid to access the personal data of that user in Firestore.